# Pop up info window on google map given coordinates

Tags: google-maps

I wonder is there a way to automatically pop up the infoWindow of a marker provided a coordinate. I want to click a link on the page from which I will get a geolocation, (and this location has already been marked on the map) With this coordinate, the corresponding infoWindow will pop up just like I clicked it on the map. Does anyone have a clue how to do that?

Thanks.

--

Generally, it's like what you can do with Google Maps, if you have multiple locations on the left, you click one, the corresponding marker on the map will pop up an infoWindow.

Comment: This question has to few information. Which page? Yours? Which location do you want to show? Do you want the location shown on google maps or do you want your own map? Which technologies do you want to use? JavaScript? Server-sided?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's possible, all you need is a reference to the related marker, then you may trigger a click on the marker, and the infoWindow will open.

How to get the reference to the marker depends on your application(the way you create the markers and the links)

Comment: Yeah, I believe I found a way of doing that, I didn't know there was a trigger method for event.